# Counting the forests obtainable by removing subtrees from binary trees

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization, extremal-graph-theory

Let $B_h$ be the *perfect* binary tree having height $h$ (i.e. the binary tree with height $h$ in which all interior nodes have two children and all leaves have the same depth or same level).

For any rooted tree $T$, we denote by $r(T)$  its root. For instance, $r(B_3)$ is the root of the perfect binary tree having height $3$.

Let $F_{h,m}$ be the set of *all* possible forests that ***(i)*** are formed by at most $m>1$ trees and ***(ii)*** can be obtained by removing from *any* tree $B_{h}$ (for all $h>1$) all nodes (together with their incident edges in $B_h$) of any subtree $T'$ of $B_h$ rooted at $r(B_h)$ (thus we have $r(T')=r(B_h)$).

---

**Question**: How can we calculate (or bounding from above) the cardinality of $F_{h,m}$ asymptotically when $h\to\infty$ (as a function of $m$ and $h$)? Does the bound $|F_{h,m}|\le\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{2^h}{i}$ hold for all $h, m>1$?

Comment: [Cool question] I think I’m unsure about your definition of $B_n$.  There is only one binary tree with 2^h leaves and height h.  Do you mean something involving labelling the vertices?  Or maybe you mean instead “B_n is the set of all rooted binary trees with n leaves where each internal node has exactly two children.”  In this second interpretation, |B_n| is given by the Catalan numbers.  I’m also not sure I understand the definition of F_{n,m}.

Comment: Maybe some examples would help.

Comment: I meant "perfect binary tree", according to the following definition (from wikipedia): "A perfect binary tree is a binary tree in which all interior nodes have two children and all leaves have the same depth or same level."

Comment: So $B_n$ has only one element? Are the leaves of $T'$ roots of the trees of $F_{n,m}$?

Comment: I edited the problem text. I am talking about "perfect binary trees". $B_n$ has infinite elements, because for any given height $h$ we have exactly one perfect binary tree. The leaves of $T'$ are nodes of the tree $T$ of $B_n$ for which $T'$ is a subtree of $T$.

Comment: $B_n$ cannot be infinite as it bounds the number of leaves in the tree. The current definition implies that $B_n$ is nonempty only if $n=2^h$, in which case it contains a single element.

Comment: I am sorry Max Alekseyev, of course. *Given any number of leaves n that is a power of 2*, then |B_n|=1. If $n$ is *not* a power of $2$, then $|B_n|$=0. I expressed myself in the wrong way, sorry.

Comment: I rephrased the problem text according to your last comments and suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that $\text{Vertices}(T') \subset\text{Vertices}(T)$ and $\text{Edges}(T')\subset\text{Edges}(T)$? Do you mean that $\text{Leaves}(T')=\text{Roots}(F_{h,m})$ or that $\text{Leaves}(T')\cap\text{Roots}(F_{h,m})=\emptyset$ ? Thanks

Comment: I mean that, given *any* $T\in B_h$, $T'$ can be *any* **subtree** of $T$ such that ***(i)*** the root of $T'$ is the same root of $T$, and ***(ii)*** the number of subtrees of $T$ that we obtain by removing all nodes of $T'$ from $T$ (together with all incident edges in $T$), is equal to $m$.

Comment: $B_h$ still consists of a single element.

Comment: Max Alekseyev, yes, exactly. I told you above that for a given number of leaves it contains only one element (or zero) as you said. Now, we have $|B_h|=1$ for all $h$. Do you have any suggestion about how to upper bound $|F_{h,m}|$?

Comment: Then what's the point in saying "any tree $T\in B_h$" while $B_h$ contains just a single element?

Comment: Rephrased, thanks.

Comment: But now saying : 

"Let $F_{h,m}$ be the set (....) by removing from *any* tree $B_{h}$"

what is the point of saying **any tree $B_{h}$** if $h$ is already given as index in $F_{h,m}$. Is the $h$ in $B_h$ the same $h$ of $F_{h,m}$ or not?

Comment: I understand that the single-tree forest $\{B_h\}$ is not an element of $F_{h,m}$, because the root of $B_h$ is a vertex of no forest in $F_{h,m}$. So $\text{card}(F_{h,1})=2^h-2$, is this correct? Thanks

Comment: $F_{h,1}=\{B_h\}$ for all $h$ (in the special pathological case $m=1$, you must remove an empty tree $T'$ formed by $0$ nodes). Hence, $|F_{h,1}|=1$ for all $h$.

Comment: Dear Penalope sorry, I am confused. **1)** Who is now $T$? I understand $T=B_h$. And **2)** removing from $B_h$ a subtree $T'$ with the same root, in such a way to obtain a connected tree, you obtain $2^h-2$ different subtrees of $B_h$ don't you? **3)** Why the empty tree $T'$ is allowed, given that it is stated that $T'$  has a root $r(T')=r(T)$?

Comment: I am sorry Pietro, you are right. I forgot to change consistently the rest of the problem text after the last modifications regarding the notation of $B_h$. Corrected now. Thanks

Comment: Dear Pietro, I also replaced $m$ by $m>1$ to avoid insignificant pathological cases.

Comment: Let's try for example $h=1$. So $B_1$ is a $\vee$-shaped     tree with three vertices, say a root $R$ and leaves $A$ and $B$. There are $3$ subtrees $T'$ of $B_1$ with the same root  of $ B_1 $, plus the empty subtree that has no root.

Comment: If we remove $T'=\{R\}$ we get a $2$-trees forest made by $A$ and $B$ as $0$-height trees. If we remove $T'$ = an edge of $B_1$, we find either $A$ or $B$ as a single-tree forests. If we remove $T'=B_1$, **(is it allowed?)** we find the empty forest. If we remove $T'=\emptyset$ (which should not be allowed according to ***ii*** ),  we find a single-tree forest made by $B_1$ itself. So what are the cardinalities $|F_{1,1}|$ and $|F_{1,2}|$?

Comment: $|F_{1,1}|=2$, $|F_{1,2}|=1$ and $|F_{1, 0}|=1$, but since $m>1$, we only focus (if $h=1$) on $|F_{1,2}|=1$.

Comment: So you wrote  "$F_{h,m}$ are all possible forests that are formed by at most $m>1$ trees", but I guess you mean instead "$F_{h,m}$ are all possible forests that are formed by *more than one tree*,   and at most $m$ trees".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is convenient to consider the vertex set of $B_h$ as a partially ordered set with its natural genealogic order, with minimum element its root. Any subtree $T'$ as described in your procedure (also including the empty tree) is then exactly an *initial segment*.  (For the notation: $B_1$ is the one-vertex tree, and so on)

Removing $T'$ from $B_h$ leaves  a set of $m$ complete trees, whose $m$ roots constitue exactly an $m$-*antichain* in the partial order. The only $0$-antichain is the empty set and produces the empty forest. The $1$-antichains are the vertices as singletons; there are $2^{h}-1$ of them, including the root. The number of forests with *exactly* $m$ trees in $B_h$ obtained removing a $T'$ is therefore the number $a_{h,m}$ of all $m$-antichains in $B_h$. So in your question $|F_{h,m}|=\sum_{2\le j\le m}a_{h,j}$, since you like to consider forests with more than one, and no more than $m$ trees. There is a clear convolution formation passing from antichains in $B_h$ to antichains in $B_{h+1}$, giving the recursive relation for the generating polynomial $P_h(x):=\sum_{m\ge0}a_{h,m}x^m$, $$\cases{P_{0}(x)=1\\P_{h+1}(x)=x+P_h(x)^2.}$$

(and of course $P_{h}(x)/(1-x)$ counts antichains with at most $m$ elements in $B_h$). The problem of counting antichains in posets is well-studied. Here is a 2006 paper "[*Counting chains and antichains in the complete binary tree*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220620320_Counting_chains_and_antichains_in_the_complete_binary_tree)" 
you may want to request to the authors (Though I'm not sure if it address the $m$-element version). Incidentally, note that $P_h(1)$, the number of all antichains in $B_h$, is the sequence [A003095](https://oeis.org/A003095).

**Edit.** In fact, if you want an asymptotics for $a_{h,m}$ as $h\to+\infty$ for each fixed $m$, this is easily available: It follows by induction that for any $m$
$$a_{h,m} \sim {2^{mh}\over m!} \quad\text{ as }\;h\to+\infty, $$
so that the bound given by  Emil Jeřábek in comment below in terms of $m$-elements subsets of $B_h$ is also an asymptotic, since
$$  {2^{mh}\over m!} \sim { 2^{h}-1\choose m } \quad\text{as }h\to+\infty. $$ Indeed we  have, for $m=1$:
$$a_{h,1} =2^{h}-1\sim  2^{h}\quad\text{as }h\to+\infty,$$
while for $m>1$,
$$a_{h+1,m}=\sum_{j=0}^m a_{h,j}a_{h,m-j}= 2a_{h,m}+\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} a_{h,j}a_{h,m-j}$$
so  assuming by complete induction hypothesis that $a_{h,j}\sim {2^{jh}\over j!}$ as $h\to+\infty$ holds for each $ j<m$, we find
$$a_{h+1,m}-  2a_{h,m}\sim {2^{mh}\over m!}\, \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} {m!\over j!(m-j)!} \,=\,{ 2^m-2\over m!} \,2^{mh}$$
or, dividing by $2^ {h+1 }$
$${a_{h+1,m}\over2^{ h+1 }}-  {a_{h ,m}\over2^{ h  }}\sim  { 2^{m-1}-1\over m!}\,2^{(m-1)h} $$
whence, summing from $0$ to $h-1$ 
$${a_{h ,m}\over 2^{ h  }}\sim  {2^{m-1}-1\over m!}\,\sum_{j=0}^{h-1}2^{(m-1)j}={2^{(m-1)h}-1\over m!}\sim{2^{(m-1)h}\over m!} $$
so that 
$$a_{h,m} \sim {2^{mh}\over m!} \quad\text{as }h\to+\infty.$$

Comment: Rmk: in the second paragraph I wrote, *leaves* is meant as third-person singular of *to leave*, not as plural of *leaf*. This topic is irredeemably doomed with ambiguity :(

Comment: One might note that the number of $m$-element antichains is trivially at most $\binom{2^h-1}m$ (the number of all $m$-element subsets), which implies the bound at the end of the question.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek in fact your bound is really accurate, for the number of $m$-element antichains turns out to be  asymptotic to that of all $m$-elements subsets for $h\to\infty$ for each fixed $m$

Comment: Thank you very much Pietro! :)